# Flask Site on Azure showing default landing page

Tags: python, git, azure, flask

I have a site that's running fine locally. I used this resource (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/) to push it up to my Azure Flask web app via Git. However, when navigating to the url given by the project:[image: Azure blade]

it looks like this:[image]
, which is not my home page. Any idea why this is happening or what I can do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, assumption that you created the webapp for using Flask via creating a Flask template from gallery on Azure old portal or from marketpacke on Azure new portal, so that the template project for Flask called `FlaskWebProject` would be created by following the webapp. You can see the template project at the path `\site\wwwroot` of the Kudu console `http://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

[image]

Therefore, you need to cover the project with your project called the same name via Git. Your project directory must be in the root path of Git repository.

```
The root path of Git repo
|- FlaskWebProject
   |- ...
```

Then, it will cover the old project when you pull the git repo via continuous deployment on Azure.

If using Visual Studio as your default IDE, you can refer to the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-flask-app/.